# Use an instance in all the project

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

i tried this on the optionViewController :

```
protocol OptionControllerDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func changeMapDisplayMode(controller: OptionController)
}
class OptionController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: OptionControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func changeMapType(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.changeMapDisplayMode(self)

    }
}
```

and this in the traceViewController :

```
class TraceController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, OptionControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapKit: MKMapView!
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var location: CLLocation!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapKit.setUserTrackingMode(.Follow, animated: true)
        mapKit.delegate = self

        let optionController = OptionController()
        optionController.delegate = self

        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
    func changeMapDisplayMode(controller: OptionController) {
        print("bonjour")

        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Map Types", message: "Select map type:", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

        let normalMapTypeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Normal", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alertAction) -> Void in
            //self.viewMap.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
            self.mapKit.mapType = .Standard
        }

        let satelliteMapTypeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Satellite", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alertAction) -> Void in
            //self.viewMap.mapType = kGMSTypeTerrain
            self.mapKit.mapType = .Satellite
        }

        let hybridMapTypeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Hybrid", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alertAction) -> Void in
            self.mapKit.mapType = .Hybrid
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (alertAction) -> Void in

        }

        actionSheet.addAction(normalMapTypeAction)
        actionSheet.addAction(satelliteMapTypeAction)
        actionSheet.addAction(hybridMapTypeAction)
        actionSheet.addAction(cancelAction)

        presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

but it doesn't work the print("bonjour") was not display as well.
When i tap on the changeMapType button it just do anything...
do you have some ideas ? :/

Comment: what is your purpose for reusing it? how will the screen look? should it actually be a child view controller owned part of the screen?

Comment: i have a first screen with the map and i have an other screen (option screen) where i want to change the map type so i have 2 view controllers the first for displaying the map and the second for the option according to this map and other like disconnection etc..

Comment: Would be better to have two separate instances of MKMapView and just pass any variable(s) that you need to make them look similar through a delegate or setting as a property (e.g. map's center, current map type etc)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to share an instance of a view in different places of an application.

There are multiple options here.

Maybe the best one is to use a delegate that will allow `OptionController` to send messages to `TraceController`.

Add a delegate to `OptionController` :

```
protocol OptionControllerDelegate {
    func changeMapDisplayMode(...) 
}

class OptionController: UIViewController {
    ...
    weak var delegate : OptionControllerDelegate
    ...
}
```

And implement the delegate methods in `TraceController`

```
class TraceController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, OptionControllerDelegate {
    ...
    optionController.delegate = self // Do this on the instance of OptionController
    ...
    func changeMapDisplayMode(...) {
        // Do stuff
    }
    ...
}
```